# I can't edit grid template area with my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid, web-frontend

i can't edit my grid template area throught my javascript
i write code to make code update the node map and this part of code is to evaluate node map to grid template area but i couldnt figure it out how to solve this problem can some help me please

```js
createMap() {
        let gridTemplate = []
        let str = ``
        this.map.forEach(xLayer => {
            let row = xLayer.map(a => {
                //convert a to [a.name, a.position] if a is not blank space
                a = (a == '.') ? '.' : `[${a[0]}, ${a[1]}]`
                return a
            })

            str += `"${row.join(' ')}"`
            gridTemplate.push(row.join(' '))
        })
        document.getElementById("viewer").style.gridTemplateAreas = `
        "${gridTemplate[0]}"
        "${gridTemplate[1]}"
        "${gridTemplate[2]}"
        "${gridTemplate[3]}"
        "${gridTemplate[4]}"
        "${gridTemplate[5]}"
        "${gridTemplate[6]}"
        "${gridTemplate[7]}"
        "${gridTemplate[8]}"
        "${gridTemplate[9]}"
        "${gridTemplate[10]}"
        "${gridTemplate[11]}"
        "${gridTemplate[12]}"
        "${gridTemplate[13]}"
        "${gridTemplate[14]}"
        `
        console.log(document.getElementById("viewer").style.gridTemplateAreas)
        //
    console.log(gridTemplate)
    //alot of
}
```

i try decrease the line of grid template, but it work when line is lower than 5

Comment: What debugging have you done? e.g. what do you see in xlayer and then in the viewer element?

Comment: In viewer is `<section Id="viewer"></section>` in x layer is ['. . . . . . . .' * 15 ] I just run the html trough live server in vsc